# Using CiviCRM for Fundraising Pipeline

Tags: activities, best-practice

Have you found an easy way to manage a fundraising pipeline using CiviCRM?

If so, can you please share how you set it up?

Thank you.

---

Thanks everyone for your responses!  To clarify, this is for tracking foundations, not individual donors. We would like to be able to see where we are in the process with a particular funder. Initial Inquiry, Proposal Sent, Under Consideration, Accepted, Denied

Comment: Can you explain a little more about what you mean with 'fundraising pipeline'?

Comment: There is CiviContribute, through which you can set up contribution pages and personal campaigns. There is also a way to assign jobs to individuals with civicrm access. So I think your answer is yes, but t depends on what you mean by pipeline, as ErikH points out.

Answer (score 4):

That's a huge question- but the answer is "yes", it's all there, but you need to do your homework. A combination of rules (check out the civi rules extension) tags and smart groups can automate just about anything you'd find in a donor pipeline.

Answer (score 3):

Yes - there are a number of organizations who use CiviCRM to manage all aspects of a fundraising pipeline!

From prospecting & donor segmentation to identify donors and calculate appropriate ask amounts, to assigning such prospects to phoners or door-to-door fundraisers right down to civimail to send immediate thank you-s and scheduled reminders to follow up later.

Answer (score 3):

As the others stated, yes it should all be possible but it will require some thought and configuration. If you want to find out what CiviRules can do you can have a look at the cookbook on the wiki: https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CiviRules+Cookbook. There is a section with an example of donor segmentation which will not answer the full scope of donor pipeline but might give you some ideas on what is possible.

Answer (score 3):

With that clarification, what you would actually want is a setup using CiviCase.  Per the Civi Book:

> CiviCase is a tool for tracking and managing sequences of interactions
>   between people in your organisation and contacts in CiviCRM.

Per the wiki for CiviCase:

> - Cases involve a sequence of interactions (*activities*). The record of
>     these activities form a narrative for the case.
> - Case management settings can classify their cases into a known set of *case types*.
> - Cases of a given type often have a predictable sequence of activities
>     (a standard timeline). Creating a schedule with the expected activity
>     sequence is a useful way to measure case progress...
> - Case management settings may have additional people and / or organizations who are frequently contacted / involved with most or all cases (case
>     resources).

There are a number of resources for CiviCase, including:

- From the book: [What Is CiviCase?](https://book.civicrm.org/user/current/case-management/what-is-civicase/)
- From the wiki: [CiviCase Configuration](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CiviCase+Configuration)
- From CiviCon Denver: [CiviCase Showcase (video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=THml_bBWa00)